# import database through cmd in linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to import database file through cmd because its size is too big.

I have tried following command,

/opt/lampp/bin $ mysql.exe -u root -p db_name <~ filename.sql

but it gives

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using
>   readline 6.3 Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
>   All rights reserved.

and open help of mysql command.

I cant get the problem.
 Please help

Comment: You have a ~ lost in there,remove it

Comment: m using it for path of file.sql 
I have kept my file at home directory only.

Comment: so if I remove ~ then it will give error - No such file or directory.

Comment: Then use the absolute path

Comment: I tried and it is giving different error:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: why I cnt connect to mysql server? If u have any idea then please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following cmd, make sure of the sql file path is correct, as well as you do not have any spaces after `-`:

```
spawn mysql -u dbUser -h hName -pdbPass dbName < db_schema.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it is giving error like,
Python error: <stdin> is a directory, cannot continue

Comment: what tool are you using to run this command? Are you running it within python interpreter? Make sure you are using the Linux terminal

Comment: @user3890150: `python` error thrown does not seem to be an SQL error. Your `py` code must be having errors.

Comment: m running in terminal only. what is the solution ? I still cnt get.

Comment: Try running an SQL script with a simple insert of only one line, just for testing. Make sure of the full path being used in your script. Try running the command without spawn.

Comment: I tried but it cant connect mysql server and showing error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) But I dnt have mysqld folder in my run folder. and also it does not allow to create folder there.

Comment: have you actually installed mysql-server?? Make sure that you have installed the mysql-server, not the mysql-client or something else. 
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path of the SQL file *filename.sql*

Answer (score 0):

1.Log into the mysql terminal and create database say dbName (Make sure that this db name corresponds to the db you are importing)

```
$mysql -u dbUser -p 
mysql> create database dbName;
```

Here dbUser must be replaced with you db user name or 'root'(which is the most probable one used) and dbName must be replaced with your database name.

Also check if the database is created using following command

```
mysql>show databases;
```

2.Exit to the terminal and give the command:

```
mysql>exit

$mysql -u dbUser -p dbName < '/full/path/to/sql_file.sql'
```

3.Enter the sql prompt and see if the database is there, and also check if all the db is imported.

```
$mysql -u dbUser -p 
mysql> show databases;
mysql> use dbName;
mysql> show tables;
```